Exclude directories from the resulting build without breaking existing module aliases
In a Node.js project, there are two directories in the project root containing .ts files - src and test. src/index.js imports module-alias/register. Every file under test/ imports module-alias/register.
Here's my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [ "./src/*" ],
    }
  },

  "include": ["test/**/*", "src/**/*", "test"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}

Node-level module aliases from my package.json:
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@": "./src"
  },

Whenever I do rm -rf dist && yarn tsc, the dist directory is created with two subdirectories inside - src and test. I only want compiled  (.js) src contents in there, not the src directory itself. As for the test directory, I don't want it at all.

tsc will emit files as they are resolved from the origin of the tsc-config (using longest common path). So the file structure you're reporting seems to be correct. If you want to alter that behavior, you can utilize rootDir.
You do not need to set baseUrl if you're also are setting paths (After 4.1).
If you don't want to emit test, you should not include it in the build. Anything you include will be emitted by tsc. Alternatively you could make different configs, one for development and one for production, and use whichever suits the use-case. Have a look at extends
